# How to do URL masking?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How do I make:

http://ecorustic.com/model.php?category=Destinations&name=destindere&id=138

appear as:

http://ecorustic.com/Destinations/destindere

to the user but the page to still point at:

http://ecorustic.com/model.php?category=Destinations&name=destindere&id=138

?
I tried the following code but link remained unchanged :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z-]+/[A-Za-z-]+/[A-Za-z-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  model.php?category=$1&name=$2&id=$3
```

Comment: By what magic are we supposed to infer the ID?

Comment: Can 138 be derived from "destindere" in a database? If so, then yes this can be done - the first step is to remove the `id` query string requirement in the model.php URL, and do the lookup internally.

Comment: the id is given when the page is parsed, and it's the id of the page in the database

Comment: Have a look at mod_rewrite if you are using the Apache HTTP server.

Comment: i did but it gives the exact oposite of what i want, it transforms the second link into the first :( , in all examples i found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  
RewriteRule ^ model.php?category=%1&name=%2&id=%3 [L]
```

sample

http://ecorustic.com/Destinations/destindere/138

Rewrite to

http://ecorustic.com/model.php?category=Destinations&name=destindere&id=138

Comment: i need :
http://ecorustic.com/model.php?category=Destinations&name=destindere&id=138 to be transformed into http://ecorustic.com/Destinations/destindere/138 not the other way around

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [the HTTP URL rewriting guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) on Apache. You said:

> i did but it gives the exact oposite of what i want, it transforms the
>   second link into the first :( , in all examples i found

It's true and that's exactly what you want: make the fancy url appear to the user while in the background it is converted to the bad url to be read by the server.

There are thousands of tutorials and guides for any need on that. Here's some:

- [Guide 1](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)
- [Guide 2](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: yes but how do make the fancy url appear??? that's what i don't get cause i already have the "bad" url, in those tutorial it explaines how to get the "bad" url based on the fancy url, BUT i need to get the fancy url based on the "bad" url(the url the visitors need to see is the fancy,but they see the "bad" url);

Comment: @Johny, you don't *get* the url, it's the fancy url that is translated in the *bad* url by the `mod_rewrite`. So that whan you write `host.com/post/1/` it will be redirected to `host.com?page=post&id=1`. To do this you have to learn how to use mod rewrite of Apache by following the urls I've posted.